# Calling a threaded function of the MKL from python: openmp library not found?

Tags: python, openmp, ctypes, intel-mkl

I am using the `ctypes` module to load the Intel MKL into python and then I'd like to call a routine that requires openmp parallelization (`pardiso`, in my case)

I found [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-your-python-programs/) useful link on the Intel sites that details the process, and I can run their example code, but when I run my own example that uses an openmp threaded function, the program crashes with the message

```
python: symbol lookup error: /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/072/mkl/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs
```

I strongly suspect that loading the `libmkl_rt.so` doesn't properly trigger a load of `libiomp5.so`

I have tried adding the Intel MKL library paths (*and* the "normal" Intel library paths) to both `LD_RUN_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to no avail, although in these paths both the mkl libraries and the openmp library (intel version) are contained.

What's the magic trick here?

Note that although I also use `numpy`, I have not built `numpy` against the mkl. But I doubt that this should matter, because I should be able to call stuff from the mkl without doing anything with numpy in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

NVM, turns out I had an older version of the MKL installed.

Following the instructions on the link I gave for versions older than 10.3 I got it up and running.